# How to find "Text" is present in which file?

Tags: file, search, directory

we have e commerce site [ magento ]

we have a lot of folders and files .

I want to edit some "text" in the file. But I am not getting from which file it is coming.

I am using ftp filezilla software.

Even I have the folders in local system.

Is there any software that can help me to find the text in entire folder structure?

Comment: `fgrep -r "some text" .` if either (unspecified) os supports it.

Comment: we are using Ubuntu OS . is i have to run this command from root....

Comment: from the root of where the magento files are, yes.

Comment: please post your comment as answer....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the Ububtu system

`fgrep -r "`*some text*`"`

in the root of the Magento install